# How to write regex or any replace function to replace with null where [,-] pattern exist

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-data-integration-hub

I am trying to create logic using informatica to replace wherever ',' followed by '-' exist [,-] replace with null.

Input :

```
abc-cde@gmail.com,-cde@gmail.com,-efg@gmail.com
ghi@gmail.com,-acf@gmail.com
```

Output :

```
abc-cde@gmail.com,cde@gmail.com,efg@gmail.com
ghi@gmail.com,acf@gmail.com
```

I have tried REPLACESTR,REPLACECHAR but its not working as pattern its considering both of them as single character and replacing wherever it is , or -.I need to build logic where it consider it as pattern of ,followed by - and then replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show your code, as most likely you're doing something wrong. The [REPLACESTR](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/transformation-language-reference/functions/replacestr.html) function should be working perfectly fine in your scenario.

Syntax:

```
REPLACESTR ( CaseFlag, InputString, OldString1, [OldString2, ... OldStringN,] NewString )
```

Check this example:

```
REPLACESTR( 1, WEBLOG, '"', 'GET ', ' HTTP/1.1', NULL )
```

Input:

```
"GET /companyinfo/index.html HTTP/1.1"
```

Result:

```
/companyinfo/index.html
```

Seems the following should work for you:

```
REPLACESTR( 1, inputField, ',-', NULL )
```

Comment: Thank you,yes its working fine with REPLACESTR